# Why does lower perplexity indicate better generalization performance?

Tags: machine-learning, model-selection, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

In the seminal paper on [Latent Dirichlet Allocation](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Eblei/papers/BleiNgJordan2003.pdf), the authors state that,

> A lower perplexity score indicates better generalization performance.
>
> $perplexity(D_{test})=exp\Big\{-\frac{\sum_{d=1}^{M}log[p(\textbf{w}_d)]}{\sum_{d=1}^{M}N_d}\Big\}$

As I understand, perplexity is directly proportional to log-likelihood. Thus, higher the log-likelihood, lower the perplexity.

**Question:**

- Doesn't increasing log-likelihood indicate over-fitting? Criteria like [AIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) and [BIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion) are specifically designed to take into account likelihood and penalize for number of parameters in the model to avoid over-fitting. Why is lower perplexity an indicator of better generalization performance?

Comment: "perplexity is directly proportional to log-likelihood" — that can't be right.  They're in different units.

Comment: I stand corrected, it should be inversely proportional to log-likelihood.

Comment: Still, not quite, because log-likelihood is in bits (or nats or hartleys), and perplexity is a count of states, which is like "$e$ to the power of bits".

Answer (score 3):

This has less to do with perplexity, and more to do with cross-validation and **test perplexity** specifically. Here's a fuller excerpt from the paper, emphasis mine:

> The perplexity,
>   used by convention in language modeling, is **monotonically decreasing in the likelihood of the test
>   data**, and is algebraicly equivalent to the inverse of the geometric mean per-word likelihood. A
>   lower perplexity score indicates better generalization performance.

I.e, a lower perplexity indicates that the data are *more* likely. As referenced in your equation, the authors are calculating *test set perplexity*. In other words, they're estimating how well their model generalizes by testing it on unseen data. Incidentally, this allows them a practical comparison with competing models whose parameter spaces could be vastly different.

It's worth noting that your intuition—about higher log-likelihood or lower perplexity and overfitting—would well suit a *training set*. As overfitting occurs, a curve of training and test perplexity should resemble the learning curve plots you're probably familiar with: Training perplexity should continue decreasing but flatten out as overfitting occurs, while test perplexity should decrease and then increase in a parabolic sort of shape.

Comment: Does make sense, that they are evaluating perplexity on the test set. I also expected a parabolic shape for perplexity on test set, but the authors have an exponentially decaying one with increasing topics.

Comment: True. Can't say for sure, but I suspect that indicates that their training and test data are rather similar.